# Como fazer uma autenticação com token (JWT)?

Tags: python, angular, http, post, jwt

Boa noite, galera!
Já tentei de 3 formas diferentes, porém o mais próximo que cheguei foi o código que postarei abaixo, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação como estudo utilizando Angular e Python e atualmente já faço a validação do meu usuário sem a utilização de token, agora estou tentando implantar porém não consigo inserir o token no meu browser.

Segue trechos de código:

Meu backend em Python:

```
class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('password', type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        password = hashlib.md5(args['password'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = (%s) and password = (%s)"
        value = (args['username'], password)
        dbcursor.execute(sql, value)
        result = dbcursor.fetchall()
        if len(result) > 0:
            return {"message": "user valido"}
            id_user = result[0][0]
            payload = {"id": id_user}
            token = jwt.encode(payload, config.JWT.secret, algorithm='HS256')
            data = json.dumps({"id": id_user, "username": result[0][1], "token": token.decode("UTF-8)")})
            res = Response(str(data),mimetype='application/json')
            res.headers['x-access-token'] = "JWT"+token.decode("UTF-8")
        else:
            return {"message": "user invalido"}

    def get(self):
        token = request.cookies.get("JWT")
        if not token:
            return {"message": "Faca login na aplicacao primeiro"}
        token = jwt.decode(token, config.JWT.secret, algorithm='HS2556')
        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where id = (%s)"
        value = (str(token["id"]),)
        dbcursor.execute(sql, value)
        result = dbcursor.fetchall()
        return result
```

Meu service utilizando Angular:

```
  authenticate(username: string, password: string) {    
    return this.http
      .post(
        API_URL,
        { "username":username, "password":password },
        { observe: 'response' } ) 
      .pipe(tap(res => {
        const authToken = res.headers.get('x-access-token')
        console.log(authToken)
      }))
  }
```

Meu componente com Angular:

```
  userLogin(){
    const username = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    const password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.authService
        .authenticate(username, password)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      if (res ["message"] == 'user valido') {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
      }
      else {
        console.log('Caiu no else')
        this.loginForm.reset()
        this.platformDetectorService.isPlatformBrower() && 
        this.usernameInput.nativeElement.focus()        
      }
    }
  )}
```

Desta forma ele acaba não validando meu usuário (cai no else), printa meu authToken como null e não registra o token no browser, algum norte ou dica ? Obrigado :)

Comment: Não manjo de Python, mas a linha `return {"message": "user valido"}` não deveria estar na linha anterior ao `else`? Depois de fazer a requisição para o servidor, guarde o token em algum lugar (SessionToken, LocalStorage ou Cookie, da pra salvar em uma variável, mas é meio tosco)

Comment: Justamente, você colocou o `return {"message": "user valido"}` logo no começo do bloco e a execução se encerra neste ponto e não finaliza o processo de autenticação.

Comment: Opa, então, eu já havia tirado também e mesmo assim não funciona, brother.
O print do token no meu componente angular ainda é nulo, primeiro eu gostaria de printar ele, depois q eu realmente estiver pegando ele eu vou armazenar no localStorage